# Performance required for histology data?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

The question is as follows: How accurate does computer vision be for it to be practically useful for analyzing histology images?

Reason I'm asking because I have seen hundreds of papers like *[Hierarchical Approach for Breast Cancer Histopathology Images Classification](https://openreview.net/forum?id=rJlGvTojG)*. They are all quite similar in that they propose a novel adaptation to an existing machine learning technique (such as deep learning) and get "very good" results. Abstract of the linked article claims 95% accuracy on the validation data.

But what accuracy (wrt detection and classification) is good enough for histology? I'm not asking about cv in general, only about cv as applied to medical image analysis. What is required for it to replace human image analysis?

Comment: Good enough for what? For publishing a paper? For using in practice?

Comment: Good question. My two cents: (significantly) better than a human would qualify as good enough.

Comment: @user31264 Since I've read the papers I know what good enough for publishing is. :) My question is about applications in histology. I know the default answer is "it depends" so I want to hear from histology experts exactly what it depends on.

Comment: I am not a histology expert, but in general, for medical diagnosis we need specificity and sensitivity, rather than accuracy on some standard dataset.  But if you want to ask histology experts, maybe you need a different forum.